# Stripe Custom Layout React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate stripe on my mobile app
I tried to import  CardField from '@stripe/stripe-react-native' but the problem is I can't change its style I want the number field to be on the line as so for both CVC and expiry date.
is there a way to do this I checked the documentation I only found this example

Comment: You can check this doc https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

Comment: still, PaymentElement isn't what I want I want each one alone so I can customize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for using the `CardField` with `stripe-react-native` are here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=custom#react-native-create-checkout-page

The CardField support some styling via `style` and `cardStyle` as shown in the example:

```
<CardField
    cardStyle={{
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      textColor: '#000000',
    }}
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: 50,
      marginVertical: 30,
    }}
  />
```